# connecting google cloud sql to spotfire

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, database-connection

I'm trying to connect google cloud SQL to Tibco Spotfire. In Spotfire I opened the "information designer" -> "setup data source" and chose MySQL5. In the connection URL I have `jdbc:mysql://google/recommendation_spark5?cloudSqlInstance=project-luc:europe-west4:movieratings&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false` "

I get the error message: "*Cannot connect to data source 'google sql', due to invalid configuration or that the data source is not running.
Database reported:
Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception:*
" (no exception is given)

I also tried pasting the usename and password in the URL but it gives the same error. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

The Supported data sources for TIBCO Spotfire are only these below:

```
1 - Microsoft Azure SQL Database
2 - Amazon Redshift
3 - OData
```

See the [link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-cloud-p/3.0.0/doc/html/sfire-cloud-p/GUID-63FEF8E2-28CB-4627-82DB-DD151786DD9D.html), obviously Google Cloud SQL will not work now, since it's not supported yet.